# Executing batch file in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file server-side in IIS to add a printer using the printuientry call.
The problem I am facing is that I am using the Copy To Output Directory - Copy Always and the following code:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(path, "AddPrinter.bat"))
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WorkingDirectory = path,
    Arguments = ipAddress,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit(10000);
process.Close();
```

Now when deugging, I have checked the values of path and its set to 
    file:\C:\_Projects\PrinterServerV2\bin
and I have checked to see if the file and directory exist which they do.
But I get the exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The directory name is invalid
```

Any ideas please??

Comment: try to copy/paste the path from debugging in a file explorer and see.

Comment: Try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory instead of CodeBase

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user you had set in the iis configuration does have all privileges to run, access, write and read what you wanna do with your batch file.

Also try to change your ProcessStartInfo like the process will be cmd.exe and your batch file the argument.

I had a similar issue [How to execute multiples .BAT files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980504)

Answer (score 0):

try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory as path.